# Why my query is not using loose index scan in mysql?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, database-administration

mysql version : 5.0.77

Table :

```
create table cus (
   id int(11), salary varchar (50), no int(11)
) engine=innodb;
```

there is two indexes.

```
1st one : id (id,salary,no)
2nd one : no (no,salary,id)
```

Explain `select id, max(salary), no from cus where no='1' group by id;` shows it using "no" index. I think it should use "id" index as i am mentioning id column as grouping columns and using max() aggregate function on the column following the grouping columns.

when executing the query using explain statement, output in the extra column is showing (using where, using index,using temporary). I am expecting the output of extra column as "using where, using index for group by".

Can anyone explain the appropriate reason behind this issue?

Comment: create index on: `no, id, salary`, in this order. `no` must come first, since it's used in the where clause in a condition with a constant.

Comment: as i am using id column in group by,  as per the logic of loose index scan i am expecting mysql to use "id"  index instead of "no" index.

Comment: The first part of the index you have is `no`. Depending on cardinality of that value, the index might be skipped because it's faster to do a table scan than to use low cardinality index. Technically, since you're doing `MAX` - better candidate for index would be `salary, id, no`, if you have to go with composite index.

Comment: I want the above query to use "id" index. But it is using "no" query.